# SwiftUI + MacOS + Xcode: Format right side of two view HStack such that it is centered in its parent view

Tags: macos, swiftui, formatting, hstack

I have a view that contains an HStack that contains two views.  The right view contains a graph.  The left view contains labels for the graphs YAxis.  I would like to center the graph in its parent view.  If someone could point me in the right direction to accomplish this it would be appreciated.  Below is my code.

Regards,

Chris

```
import SwiftUI
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center) {
            let maxYValue = viewModel.data.max { $0.Value < $1.Value }?.Value
            let minYValue = viewModel.data.max { $0.Value > $1.Value }?.Value
            let deltaY = maxYValue! - minYValue!
            let maxYVal = Int(round(maxYValue!))
            let minYVal = Int(round(minYValue!))
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    Text(String("\(maxYVal)"))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("2")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("3")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("3")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(String("\(minYVal)"))
                }.frame(width: 100, height: 510, alignment: .trailing)
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Path { path in
                        for index in viewModel.data.indices {
                            let xPosition = ((geometry.size.width) / (CGFloat(viewModel.data.count - 1))) * CGFloat(index + 0)
                            let yPosition =  (1 - (CGFloat(viewModel.data[index].Value - minYValue!)) / CGFloat(deltaY) ) * (geometry.size.height)
                            if index == 0 {
                                path.move(to: CGPoint(x : xPosition, y : yPosition))
                            }
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x : xPosition, y: yPosition))
                        }
                    } .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    Path { path in
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: geometry.size.height))
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: geometry.size.height))
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width, y: geometry.size.height))
                    }.stroke(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                    Path { path in
                        for index in 0...3 {
                            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0 , y: geometry.size.height * CGFloat(index) / 4))
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width , y: geometry.size.height * CGFloat(index) / 4))
                        }
                    }.stroke(Color.gray, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5))
                } // end geometry reader
                .frame(width: 700, height: 500)// end inner geometry reader
            }
        } // end of vstack
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would help debugging

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response.  After posting my query I did some research and came to the conclusion that my code was too complex.  So, I rewrote it and I think simplified it.  I create a geometry reader and use it to create two rectangles that combined take up the entire parent view.  In the upper rectangle I place the graph title and in the lower rectangle I place the graph and am in the process of putting labels on the X and Y axis.  Using this approach has allowed me to exactly place items within the rectangle including centering the graph.  Problem solved.
The only thing I need to figure out is how to change the stroke for a given line without having to create multiple paths as I have done.
Below is the updated code.

Thanks again for responding.

Chris

```
import SwiftUI
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack (spacing: 0){
                let frameWidth = geometry.size.width
                let frameHeight = geometry.size.height
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
//                    .border(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight * 1/8 )
                    .overlay(
                        Text("Principal Values Over the Last Year")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    )
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight * 7/8 )
//                    .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                    .overlay(
                        PrincipalChart(frameWidth: frameWidth, frameHeight: frameHeight * 7/8)
                    )
                    .padding(0)
            } // end Vstack
        } // end geometry reader
    } // end body var
}  // end of MainView
struct PrincipalChart: View {
    let frameWidth : CGFloat
    let frameHeight : CGFloat
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let maxYValue = viewModel.data.max { $0.Value < $1.Value }?.Value
            let minYValue = viewModel.data.max { $0.Value > $1.Value }?.Value
            let deltaY = maxYValue! - minYValue!
            let maxYVal = Int(round(maxYValue!))
            let minYVal = Int(round(minYValue!))
            let yAxisStep = Int((maxYVal - minYVal) / 4)
            Path { path in
                for index in viewModel.data.indices {
                    let xPosition = (frameWidth * 1/10) + ((frameWidth * 8/10) / (CGFloat(viewModel.data.count - 1))) * CGFloat(index + 0)
                    let yPosition =  (1 - (CGFloat(viewModel.data[index].Value - minYValue!)) / CGFloat(deltaY) ) * (frameHeight * 9/10)
                    if index == 0 {
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x : xPosition, y : yPosition))
                    }
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x : xPosition, y: yPosition))
                }
            } .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frameWidth * 1/10, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frameWidth * 1/10 , y: frameHeight * 9/10 ))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frameWidth * 9/10, y: frameHeight * 9/10))
            }.stroke(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
            Path { path in
                for index in 0...3 {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frameWidth * 1/10, y: (frameHeight * 9/10) * (CGFloat (index) / 4) ))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frameWidth * 9/10, y: (frameHeight * 9/10) * (CGFloat (index) / 4)))
                }
            }.stroke(Color.gray, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5))
            Text("\(maxYVal)").position(x: (frameWidth * 1/10) - 20, y: 1)
            let stepValue3 = maxYVal - yAxisStep
            Text("\(stepValue3)").position(x: (frameWidth * 1/10) - 20, y: -2 + (frameHeight * 9/10) * 1 / 4 )
            let stepValue2 = stepValue3 - yAxisStep
            Text("\(stepValue2)").position(x: (frameWidth * 1/10) - 20, y: -2 + (frameHeight * 9/10) * 2 / 4 )
            let stepValue1 = stepValue2 - yAxisStep
            Text("\(stepValue1)").position(x: (frameWidth * 1/10) - 20, y: -2 + (frameHeight * 9/10) * 3 / 4 )
            Text("\(minYVal)").position(x: (frameWidth * 1/10) - 20, y: -2 + (frameHeight * 9/10) * 4 / 4 )
        } // end z stack
    } // end body var
}  // end Principal Chart view
```